# Javascript _self not loading next page

Tags: javascript, forms, self

Im working on a project for school where I need to make a small system that requires 2 default login "accounts" and only that.
The way I do this is with an html form which is linked to a script.

For some reason when I use `window.open('right.html');` it will put me through to the next page on a different tab once you fill in the right details.
But when I use `window.open('right.html', '_self');` it will clear the field and not go to the next page.

Here is my script:

```
    function checkform() {
        if (document.login.name.value == "Thea" && document.login.pass.value == "1234") {
            window.open('right.html');

        } else {
            if (document.login.name.value == "Theo" && document.login.pass.value == "4321") {
                window.open('right2.html', "_self");

            } else {
                return false;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use `window.location.href = "right2.html`

Comment: Yeah.... `window.open` doesn't seem like the right solution here, I agree with @Coli on this one, just set the `window.location.href` property to whatever you like, in your case `right2.html`, it'll act *kinda* like a redirect.... Also, where are you defining `self`?

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V Im not defining `self` Didn't know I needed to since this is my first js project. My teacher didn't tell me anything about it either. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Am I drunk or have you edited this slightly? - I didn't see the quotation marks around `_self`..... Either way... You should still replace that with `window.location.href = "right2.html"`. That solution is well pointless/silly really. Normally you want to use `window.open` to open a window in a new tab.... If you reassign the value of `window.location.href` then that'll just take you to the given value.... I.E. Try typing into your dev tools console `window.location.href="https://www.google.com";`.

Comment: @Jeffrey if you need help with JS, PM me, you can find a link to my personal website on my account page.